# Mamp/MYSQL permissions issue?

Tags: mysql, mamp, macos-sierra, mamp-pro

Started experiencing issues with Mamp (4) connecting to database, adding new databases etc and looks to be a permissions issue.
Set-up is Mac OS X 10.12 (Sierra)

Error getting when try to create or drop a database is `Couldn't delete the database. MySQL said: Error dropping database (can't rmdir './timesheets', errno: 13)`
Trying `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE '%datadir%';` command it is showing the data directory in use by MySQL as `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56/`

However if I try to CD to that directoy in terminal I get `No such file or directory`

Bizarrely if I try to connect to existing local MySQL databases using Sequel Pro (via socket) can access data just fine.

In terms of context, computer restarted randomly last week (assume to do with upgrade to or within OSX Sierra) which killed my bash scripts too.
However since then been able to work locally with MySQL fine but this might be the first time since then tried to create or drop a database.

Any suggestions on debugging/fixing appreciated!